# Is it possible to change the serial number of a VM in VMware Fusion?

Tags: rhel, hardware, vmware, system-information, dmidecode

I need to change the system Serial Number

it's shown in the output of

```
dmidecode -t system
```

Please note that I'm running RedHat in a virtual machine in VMware Fusion

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: KVM/qemu can do this since many years, so I would be surprised if VMWare can't do it. But somebody else will have to dig up the specifics.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VMware fusion, but in full-blown VMware, I've found the serial number in the VM's "vmx" file in the uuid.bios attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change this by changing the BIOS UUID in the VM configuration. Follow these steps:

1. Shutdown the VM and close VMware Fusion
2. Locate the .vmwarevm directory of your VM, normally Documents/Virtual Machines.localized
3. Open the vmwarevm directory, and then open the .vmx file inside of it
4. Locate the uuid.bios entry and modify it as appropriate
5. Startup Fusion and your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `dmidecode` wrapper script, somewhere earlier in the `$PATH` than the real one, that calls the original and filters the output:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/dmidecode "$@" | sed 's/Serial Number: .*$/Serial Number: new-number/'
```